# How to Extract Items From an LDAP Path String

Tags: c#, string, split, active-directory, ldap

Is there a "right" way of retrieving for example the CN from the following string:

`"LDAP://CN=Firstname Surname,OU=Domain Administrators,DC=DOMAIN1,DC=co,DC=uk"`

Which I retrieved from a `DirectorySearcher`

Currently I am doing this:

`var name = result.Path.Split('=')[1].Split(',')[0];`

But this does not feel like the best way of doing this - does anyone know of any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into this article:  [An RFC 2253 Compliant Distinguished Name Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9788/An-RFC-Compliant-Distinguished-Name-Parser)

> There are three main classes in this code:
>
> - DN, which represents a full distinguished name
> - RDN, which represents a relative distinguished name
> - RDNComponent, which represents the individual components of a    multivalued RDN
>
>   `DN myDN = new DN(@"CN=Pete Everett\, esq.,OU=People,DC=example,DC=com");`
>
> To print out a DN object, you use its ToString() method, as you'd
>   expect.
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine(myDN.ToString());
> // prints out:
> // CN=Pete Everett\, esq.,OU=People,DC=example,DC=com
> ```
>
> But if you'd like more control over the formatting, you can specify
>   categories of characters to escape.
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine(myDN.ToString(EscapeChars.None));
> // prints out:
> // CN=Pete Everett, esq.,OU=People,DC=example,DC=com
> // (Note that this is an incorrect DN format, and will not parse correctly.)
> ```
>
> To get the parent object of a given DN object, you can use its Parent
>   property.
>
> ```
> DN myParentDN = myDN.Parent;
> Console.WriteLine(myParentDN.ToString());
> // prints out:
> // OU=People,DC=example,DC=com
> ```

Comment: thanks for the link! That seems really useful. For my purposes (a simple web service with only a few AD queries) adding all those classes may be a bit overkill, but definitely seems worth a look for more general use

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on an external dependency you could use the power of pattern matching to accomplish this.

Here is a [**regular expression to extract info from ldap distinguishedNames**](https://regexr.com/3l4au) by [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com) user **Massimo Bonvicini**

And here is a basic example in C#

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = "^(?:(?<cn>CN=(?<name>[^,]*)),)?(?:(?<path>(?:(?:CN|OU)=[^,]+,?)+),)?(?<domain>(?:DC=[^,]+,?)+)$";
string dn = "CN=Exchange Servers,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=gr-u,DC=it";

Match match = Regex.Matches(myDN, pattern)[0];

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("cn").Value);
 // output: 
 // CN=Help Desk

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("name").Value);
 // output:
 // Help Desk

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("path").Value);
 // output:
 // OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("domain").Value);
 // output:
 // DC=gr-u,DC=it
```

Comment: This code has a typo, the (0) on the Match match line should be [0]